# ftlib ошибка WinError 10060

Tags: python, сеть

Использую ftlib в Python, чтобы реализовать FTP протокол у себя в программе. Программа должна кидать файлы с хоста на гостевую ОС в VirtualBox. При попытке передачи выдает ошибку **TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого
компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик**. В чем может быть проблема?

```
# Отправка файла
def send():
 if ent_dir.get() == '':
   print(ftp.pwd())
   ftp.cwd('/home/helga/Desktop')
   print(file_name)
   file_ = open(file_name, 'rb')
   ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + '/' + ent_file.get(), file_)
   ftp.quit()
 else:
    # ftp.cwd(ent_dir.get())
    print(file_name)
    file_ = open(file_name, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + '/' + ent_file.get(), file_)
    ftp.quit()

# Подключение к серверу
   def connect():
global ftp
if ent_file.get() != '':
    ftp = FTP('192.168.0.102', timeout=200)
    ftp.login('helga', '123')
    send()
else:
    Tk.messagebox.showerror('Ошибка', 'Выберите файл!')
```

---

Это то, что я получил в следствии ipconfig /all в консоли

```
C:\Users\Shepard>ipconfig /all

Настройка протокола IP для Windows
Имя компьютера  . . . . . . . . . : vice
Основной DNS-суффикс  . . . . . . :
Тип узла. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Гибридный
IP-маршрутизация включена . . . . : Нет
WINS-прокси включен . . . . . . . : Нет

Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet:

Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 8C-04-BA-39-6E-A7
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Да
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да

Адаптер Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-07
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Нет
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::c1bc:8e69:4f48:4a06%7(Основной)
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Основной)
Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . :
IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 722075687
DUID клиента DHCPv6 . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-3F-1E-CC-8C-04-BA-39-6E-A7
DNS-серверы. . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                    fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                    fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Включен

Адаптер беспроводной локальной сети Подключение по локальной сети* 1:

Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 5C-87-9C-CC-73-F7
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Да
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да 

Адаптер беспроводной локальной сети Подключение по локальной сети* 10:

Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 5E-87-9C-CC-73-F6
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Да
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да 

Адаптер Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Нет
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::590c:3e88:389b:97c8%20(Основной)
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.159.1(Основной)
Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . :
IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 687886422
DUID клиента DHCPv6 . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-3F-1E-CC-8C-04-BA-39-6E-A7
DNS-серверы. . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Включен

Адаптер Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Нет
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::f99d:1020:cebc:3092%10(Основной)
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(Основной)
Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . :
IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 704663638
DUID клиента DHCPv6 . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-3F-1E-CC-8C-04-BA-39-6E-A7
DNS-серверы. . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Включен

Адаптер беспроводной локальной сети Беспроводная сеть:

DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 5C-87-9C-CC-73-F6
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Да
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::e8e0:3965:b31c:9561%14(Основной)
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100(Основной)
Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Аренда получена. . . . . . . . . . : 28 февраля 2021 г. 19:01:53
Срок аренды истекает. . . . . . . . . . : 3 марта 2021 г. 15:09:09
Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DHCP-сервер. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 224167836
DUID клиента DHCPv6 . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-3F-1E-CC-8C-04-BA-39-6E-A7
DNS-серверы. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
                                    0.0.0.0
NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Включен

Адаптер Ethernet Сетевое подключение Bluetooth:

Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Описание. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 5C-87-9C-CC-73-FA
DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . : Да
Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
```

что я получаю в консоли, когда пытаюсь пинговать с хоста и с виртуалки

```
Host -> Linux (Virtual Box)

C:\Users\Shepard>ping 192.168.0.101
Обмен пакетами с 192.168.0.101 по с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 192.168.0.101: число байт=32 время=1мс TTL=64
Ответ от 192.168.0.101: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=64
Ответ от 192.168.0.101: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=64
Ответ от 192.168.0.101: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=64
Статистика Ping для 192.168.0.101:
Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
(0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 1 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек


Linux (Virtual Box) -> Host

ping 192.168.0.100
PING 192.168.0.100 (192.168.0.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.635 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.708 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.695 ms
...
```

Comment: Это то, что я получил в следствии ipconfig /all в консоли

Comment: Отлично! С этим уже можно жить. 192.168.0.100 - это, как я понимаю, "настоящий" адрес линуксовой виртуалки? Ну, всякую фигню, которую им там VBox напридумывал, я не считаю. А какой IP у виндового хоста? И самое главное - они друг друга  пингуют?

Comment: Вот как раз 192.168.0.100 - это IP хоста, а IP линуксовой виртуалки - 192.168.0.101. Оба друг друга пингуют

Comment: *добавил в свой ответ, что я получаю в консоли, когда пытаюсь пинговать с хоста и с виртуалки*

Comment: А что, если попробовать зайти на FTP каким то обычным ftp - клиентом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию VB поднимает сеть типа "NAT"

Это означает, что виртуальная машина "видит" интернет, и видит хост - машину, а наоброт - нет.

Нужно -для начала- проверитьэту гипотезу.Для этого приведите в вопросе IP адреса хоста и виртуалки.

В комментариях справедливо подсказывают, что в VBox есть настройка. Можно просто попробовать переключить сеть в режим bridge.

В любом случае, нужно сначала убедиться в отсутствии "общих сетевых проблем", например, добиться того, чтобы пинговалась виртуалка с хоста.

Потом проверить, что ftp-сервер запущен и порт ftp открыт и доступен для подключения (например, при помощи telnet)

А если всё это уже проделано - наверное, половить пакеты wireshark'ом, другого мне в голову не приходит

Comment: Во-первых, там есть настройка. Во-вторых, реальный комп тоже находится в сети виртуалбокса и они должны видеть друг друга. Ну при условии, что он не через интернет коннектиться пытается.

Comment: Да, там есть настройка. Но обычно на эту настройку никто не обращает внимания, пока не ударится лбом о тот факт, что хост "не видит" виртуалку. Именно поэтому я попросил уточнений. Насчет того, что хост находится в одной сети с виртуалбоксом - согласен, это могло бы решить проблему,но тогда надо првести конфиги всех сетевых интерфейсов хоста и убедиться, что пайтон работает со всеми интефейсами... я дополнил ответ

Comment: Но её сеть всё равно есть в основной системе: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwISG.png

Comment: @Qwertiy - спасибо за подробности. Действительно. Тогда - загадка! Может, Windows Firewall, ужасный и бесполезный? Автор вопроса, какая у Вас в виртуалке система и файервол?

Comment: Начну по - порядку: Хост - Windows, гостевая - Linux. В VirtualBox в разделе "Сеть" стоит "Сетевой мост".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хорошо, что проблема решилась!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена! На гостевой ОС (Linux) был включен файрвол. Его нужно отключить и тогда все будет работать.

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: Это то, что я получил в следствии ipconfig /all в консоли

Comment: Отлично! С этим уже можно жить. 192.168.0.100 - это, как я понимаю, "настоящий" адрес линуксовой виртуалки? Ну, всякую фигню, которую им там VBox напридумывал, я не считаю. А какой IP у виндового хоста? И самое главное - они друг друга  пингуют?

Comment: Вот как раз 192.168.0.100 - это IP хоста, а IP линуксовой виртуалки - 192.168.0.101. Оба друг друга пингуют

Comment: *добавил в свой ответ, что я получаю в консоли, когда пытаюсь пинговать с хоста и с виртуалки*

Comment: А что, если попробовать зайти на FTP каким то обычным ftp - клиентом?

Answer (score 0):

Нет смысла загружать файлы на виртуалку по ftp.

Надо просто установить расширения гостевой ОС на виртуалку и добавить постоянную папку. Виртуалка будет видеть её как сетевой диск (команда для подключения написана в подсказке в настройках и зависит от ОС), а для внешней системы это будет обыкновенная папка на диске, в которую вполне можно складывать файлы.

Comment: Это нужно сделать в рамках лабораторной работы